# Let H be a subgroup of finite group G. G acts on G/H by left multiplication. This induces a homomorphism. Show that its kernel is in H

Tags: group-actions, group-homomorphism

Let G be a finite group and H is a subgroup of G. We have G acts on the set of left co-sets of H  (G/H) by left multiplication x(gH)=xgH. This action induces a homomorphism from G to perm(G/H). Show that the kernel of this homomorphism is in H.

Can someone please explain this question? I don't know where to start. I know that the kernel of this homomorphism is the subgroup of G. So it also acts on G by the left multiplication.

Comment: There are some $a_j \in G$ such that $G = \bigcup_{j=1}^n a_j H$ is a disjoint union. For $g \in G$ then $G =g G= \bigcup_{j=1}^n g a_j H$ is a disjoint union. Thus $g a_j H  = a_{\sigma_g(j)} H$ for some permutation $\sigma_g$. Check $g\mapsto \sigma_g$ is an homomoprhism. For what $g$ do we have $j = \sigma_g(j)$ ?

Comment: what are you confused about? Are all the definitions clear?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $gg_1H=g_1H\,,\forall g_1\in G$, that is $g\in\operatorname{ker}\phi$, where $\phi$ is your homomorphism.   Then , in particular,  $gH=H$.  So $g\in H$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how gH=H in this case

Comment: Take $g_1\in H$.

Comment: @AlexSmith If $g$ is in the kernel of the action, it acts trivially. Thus, multiplying the "trivial coset" $H$ by $g$ simply yields $H$.